# VueJS not loading on IE11

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, internet-explorer-11

IE11 does not load my VueJS app.

I currently have a console log error: **SCRIPT1003: Expected ':'** on the below line *async*:

```
   methods: {
       async getData() {
```

I have tested using a polyfill but with no improvement, what am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Do you use webpack or other transpilers?

Comment: Not currently, just prototyping. I had thought babel + polyfill would help resolve this.

Comment: You should post your babel/webpack config as the issue is probably there.

Comment: I'm not currently using anything, working on a prototype. I'm just loading vue/axios/bootstrap-vue. Thanks

Comment: Set up a vue project using the Vue CLI https://cli.vuejs.org/. It's simple and gives you a working build/transpilation setup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have tested using a polyfill but with no improvement, what am I
>   missing?

The `async await` syntax is part of the ES2017 spec and not supported in Internet Explorer at all - alongside of many other features such as arrow functions and classes.

As mentioned in some of the comments, the only workaround here is to use a transpiler such as [babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile modern language features down to ES5, which is fully supported by IE11.

I highly recommend using [vue-cli](https://cli.vuejs.org/) to kickstart your projects, as it comes with all the build setup you need to make your application work cross-browser and many more features, such as intelligent code splitting.